# Numerical volume integration over spherical coordinates

Tags: numerical-methods, quadrature

I am trying to implement [SOAP descriptor](https://singroup.github.io/dscribe/latest/tutorials/descriptors/soap.html). For which I need to solve the projection integral of the form:

$$
c = \int \int \int_\mathcal{V} g(r) Y(\phi, \theta)e ^{k |\mathbf{r - R}|^2}sin(\theta) r^2 d\theta d\phi dr
$$

Where $k$ and $\mathbf{R}$ are some constants.

Are there any 3D equivalent of Lebedev quadrature for fast numerical integration over volume on spherical coordinates?

Comment: What is ${\cal V}\,?$

Comment: appropriate limits for integrating over the volume V.

Comment: A quadrature does not work for an arbitrary range of integration. We know that [Gauss quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature) with  $n$ weights works on $[-1,1]$ and only for functions that are well approximated by polynomials of degree $2n-1$ or less. This principle won't change in your case.

Comment: I understand that. I was hoping for some scheme like https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1968-22-102/S0025-5718-68-99878-5/S0025-5718-68-99878-5.pdf 
Which goes from lower limit r to upper limit 1. I was just hoping that there might be an efficient way of numerically integrating volume in spherical coordinates that I am not aware of.  Worst come I can always stitch together a piecewise integration over arbitrary volume using change of limits, as in the case of Gauss quadrature right? Is this reasoning wrong?

Comment: Very hard to tell. One thing is clear: `nquad` in python is easy to use and should be used to test whatever faster method you stitch together.